# Counting occurances for each element without any loop

Tags: r

I have the following vector `V1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 1)`.

I would like to have a vector V2 of the same size that for each element indicates how often the corresponding element in V1 occurs, i.e. V2 should be `c(3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3)`.

I know a multitude of ways to obtain this result, however all of them include using a loop, e.g.

```
V2 <- c()
for(k in 1:length(V1)){
  V2[k] <- length(which(V1 == V1[k]))
}
```

My question is: Is there a more elegant way of doing it, i.e. without using a loop?

Comment: `table(V1)[V1]`

Comment: @AntoniosK Thanks, exactly what I was seeking!

Comment: `ave(V1, V1, FUN = length)` might be safer

Comment: @bouncyball Well I'm using the code for a character vector actually (you were referring to the table/floating point issue right?). But thanks for the alternative, didn't know `ave`.

Comment: or try `library(tidyverse);
as.tibble(V1) %>%  group_by(value) %>% mutate(V2=n())`

Comment: @nate.edwinton my solution will work only for this example and cases where `V1` includes all values from 1 to n. It will break otherwise. There are more general solutions provided above. Another one could be `merge(data.frame(V1), data.frame(table(V1)), by="V1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summing up the solutions provided

```
# @bouncyball
ave(V1, V1, FUN = length)
# [1] 3 2 1 3 1 2 2 2 3

# @AntoniosK
table(V1)[V1]
# V1
# 1 2 3 1 4 5 5 2 1 
# 3 2 1 3 1 2 2 2 3 

# @Roman
library(tidyverse); 
as.tibble(V1) %>% group_by(value) %>% mutate(V2=n())
#   A tibble: 9 x 2
#   Groups:   value [5]
#   value    V2
#   <dbl> <int>
# 1     1     3
# 2     2     2
# 3     3     1
# 4     1     3
# 5     4     1
# 6     5     2
# 7     5     2
# 8     2     2
# 9     1     3
```